# How did all the Gods of Destruction come to see the fight?

Tags: dragon-ball-super

I thought that the Gods of Destruction sleep and once they awaken they go on a destruction spree.

But how were all the Gods of Destruction able to come to the fight in the Zen-oh exhibition match?

Comment: Zen-oh is supereme in lead of all, so every one has to obey the order :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are the god of destruction, meaning that they have a role to fulfill. Aka destroying planets. But however someone/something far more superior has passed this role on to them. That is the Zen-oh sama. He is powerful enough to wipe-out their entire universe if he wishes to in the blink of an eye. The gods... rather anyone with a role in the universe knows about his might. In order to at least stay alive they will have to abide to anything he says as he simply destroys things he doesn't like on a whim. Remember black Goku? Even Goku knew that they had to leave quickly while everyone else didn't really bother to... but they survived.

The gods that were sleeping were probably wakened by their angels (equivalents of Whis). They can ofcourse refuse, but that gives Zen-oh a chance to eradicate their entire universe, as if they never existed.

The arc from when Zen-oh was introduced up until now simply prove how much power he possesses due to the gods fearing him. And ofcourse due to the fact that any creature, with a role in making things in the universe go smoothly, shows a LOT respect and doesn't disagree with Zen-oh.

Whis for example is at least 1000x stronger than Beerus (http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Thread:541859) and he is nothing compared to Zen-oh. Beerus knows pretty well that if Whis shows respect to anyone that he should as well unless he wants to cause trouble for himself... and perhaps the entire universe.

Even the gods that know about the uhmm punishment for not winning (not trying to spoil) aren't demanding other things from him, rather they are showing kind words in a manipulative way in order to not be punished... which they would've been anyway without the universe tournament. At least now 1 won't be punished... anyway back to your question.

Apart from the unknowning creatures anyone fears Zen-oh, because in the end they all want to survive, hence why they listen instantly to anything from Zen-oh.